# How to grant runtime permissions to an android application without prompting the user

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to build an android application which when installed through Google Playstore should have access to the runtime permissions like SMS Access, Contacts, Location Service without asking the user for it.

I know it is possible since I have seen it happen in a couple of Android Applications on Playstore like 
Kotak 811 App
Standard Chartered Banking App

Does anyone know how this can be achieved even when the phone is running Android Nougat.

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to grant runtime permissions to an android application without prompting the user

**AFAIK** it is not possible

Please read  [Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> I am trying to build an android application which when installed through Google Playstore should have access to the runtime permissions like SMS Access, Contacts, Location Service without asking the user for it.

than you have to make `targetSdkVersion` lower than 23

> Does anyone know how this can be achieved even when the phone is running Android Nougat.

That is not possible and if  user manually revoke the dangerous permission you app will crash

> What are the disadvantages of doing `targetSdkVersion` lower than 23

if user manually remove permission from your app than you app get crash  in android api 23 and above

**EDIT**
**[you will not be able to ship updates to your app on the Play Store starting later in 2018](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)**

[Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Comment: What are the disadvantages of doing so ?

Comment: @AnjulGarg 
if user manually remove permission from your app than you app get crash  in android api 23 and above